# How-to use GAE Blobstore Java API with GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc, blobstore

I have GAE application and I'd like to download CSV file from Blobstore and display it in a table using GWT. Is there any example showing how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll just have to create a GWT-RPC service that reads the data from Blobstore using [`read()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream.html#read()), converts the bytes back to csv, then puts it into some reasonable format (e.g., `List<Row>` or `Map<String, Row>` for some `Row` class you write) to return to the GWT client-side code.